# How to use routes in .js.coffee script rails

Tags: javascript, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I have this code:

```
$('#my_form .submit').click( ->
  $.ajax( ->
  type: "post",
  url: "????",
  data: $("#myform").serialize(),
  #success: this.saveUserResponse
)

POST   /schedule_details(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"schedule_details"}
```

I guess this is 2 questions, or looking for the right way to do it.  How can I use a shedule_details_create_path and how can I use that in my javascript?  Or, is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about unobtrusively AJAXify the form instead of subscribing for the click handler of the submit button:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: this.saveUserResponse
    });
    return false;
});
```

This way you can generate the form using the routing and have its action attribute properly set in the markup. Then your javascript is completely independent.

Comment: Amazing, I knew I was just way over thinking it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*js-routes* gem works great for me.

Gemfile:

```
gem "js-routes"
```

Require js routes file in application.js.

```
//= require js-routes
```

Flush asset pipeline cache before trying js-routes for the first time and restart your rails server:

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
rails s
```

Finally in your coffeescript file:

```
Routes.users_path()
# => "/users"
Routes.user_path 1
# => "/users/1"
Routes.user_path 1, format: 'json'
# => "/users/1.json"
Routes.user_path 1, anchor: 'profile'
# => "/users/1#profile"
Routes.new_user_project_path 1, format: 'json'
# => "/users/1/projects/new.json"
```

For advanced configuration, just check [js-routes github repo](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes).

Comment: @dbugger okay, I'll add a few more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your routes.rb you can write something like that:

```
match "/schedule_details/create" => "schedule_details#create"
```

and put /schedule_details/create in the url: param of your ajax call.

Hope i understood your need!

Comment: The problem with just putting /schedule_details/create in the url param is my test machine uses localhost:3000/schedule_details/create, but my production machine is example.com/ts/schedule_details/create.  So the /schedule_details/create would break on the production machine.  Thank you for your info though